# Cast Objective-C block NSStackBlock into Swift 3

Tags: objective-c, swift3, delegates, wkwebview, rx-swift

I'm writing a reactive extension for one of the WKWebView navigation delegates. At the moment I wrote the following code:

```
public typealias NavigationHttpResponse = (WKWebView, WKNavigationResponse, (WKNavigationResponsePolicy) -> Swift.Void)
public var decidePolicyForNavigationResponse: Observable<NavigationHttpResponse> {
    let selector = #selector(WKNavigationDelegate.webView(_:decidePolicyFor:decisionHandler:)! as ((WKNavigationDelegate) -> (NavigationHttpResponse) -> ()))
    return delegate.methodInvoked(selector)
        .map { params in
            let webView = params[0] as! WKWebView
            let navigationResponse = params[1] as! WKNavigationResponse
            let decisionHandler = params[2] as! ((WKNavigationResponsePolicy) -> Swift.Void)
            return (webView, navigationResponse, decisionHandler)
    }
}
```

So far so good but when I launch my app add that code is executed, I get a crash when I'm trying to cast the block with the following line:

```
let decisionHandler = params[2] as! ((WKNavigationResponsePolicy) -> Swift.Void)
```

In the degub console I get:

```
Could not cast value of type '__NSStackBlock__' (0x12327d1a8) to '(__C.WKNavigationResponsePolicy) -> ()' (0x12218b8f0).
```

How can I safely cast from objective-c to Swift?
Or which alternative approach can I take?

Thanks!